# Symfony 2 - modifying form configuration after initializing a form object

Tags: forms, symfony

I was wondering if it's possible to modify form configuration after the form object has been initialized (I define my form as a service).

Namely, when creating a form in a controller, we could do this:

`$form = $this->createForm('some_form_type', $entity, ['some_key' => true]);`

but then what if I want to modify `$options` after initialization.

`FormInterface` exposes `getConfig()` method that returns `FormConfigInterface` so we have direct access to the configuration object. This object, however, does not expose any setters. `FormInterface` also does not expose any configuration setter methods.

In short, do you know of a way to modify a form configuration object after initilizaing the form object?

Comment: why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question I'd like to ask you is: *Why would you modify the form configuration after the form object is built ?*

That's actually impossible, because the configuration is locked before being used by the form builder (`FormBuilderInterface`) in order to create and initialize the form (`FormInterface`) instance.

So, *unless you use your own `FormBuilderInterface` and `FormConfigBuilder` instances not locking the configuration once build*, **you should use the form builder to properly modify anything before building the form instance**.