# Is it possible to set a custom data attribute from whithin a PRE_SET_DATA event to the form tag itself?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a **Blog** entity who has a **slug**, i want this **slug** to be saved in a custom data attribute inside the form tag like this: `<form data-article-slug="my-slug">`.

**This is what i expect to achieve:**

```
class BlogTypeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $slug = $data->getSlug();

        if (!empty($slug)) /* the bellow method does not exist */
            $form->setAttr([ 'data-article-slug' => $slug ]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [ FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData' ];
    }
}
```

It is possible to do almost the same thing inside of a twig template such as: `{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'data-article-slug' : form.vars.value.slug } }) }}` but i find this way very redundent and not symfony friendly, how can i achieve this?

Comment: do you have form type? show it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Once `$builder->getForm()` has been called the form is locked. It's part of the design, allowing to modify the form after it has been built could lead to issues because options has to be resolved and this can only be achevied through the form building process.

**Aditionally you can read this:**
[Symfony 2 - modifying form configuration after initializing a form object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266449/symfony-2-modifying-form-configuration-after-initializing-a-form-object)
**And maybe this:** https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20311

Answer (score 0):

Basically the idea is next:
You need to create(or you already have) form type:
for example

```
class YourEntityType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAttribute('somefield')
            ->setAttribute('slug');

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder){
               /** @var YOURENTITY $data */
               $data = $builder->getData();

               if ($data->getSlug()) {
                  $builder->setAttribute('data-article-slug', $data->getSlug());
               }
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => YOURENTITYCLASSNAMEHERE::class]);
    }
}

}
```

So in this example we have created an entity form type, with event listener. On set data, if you have a `slug`, then `data-article-slug` attribute will be added to a form.

Further reading:

1.[forms (see data_class)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)

2.[pre set data event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-set-data-event)